# Displaying PHP variable in HTML dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I have an SQL DB loaded with security questions and answers. I need to display them in an html dropdown. I thought I could populate the dropdown fields with a while loop but I can't get it to work.

Any idea what's wrong with this?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die (mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("assignment_3", $conn);

$data = "select securityQuestion, securityAnswer from securityquestiontable";

$result = mysql_query($data, $conn) or die (mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
print "<select>";
print "<option value=""";
print "disabled="disabled" selected="selected">";
print "Please Select your Undergraduate School";
print "</option>";
print "<option value="1">";
print $row["securityQuestion"];
print "</option>";
print "<option value="2">";
print $row["securityAnswer"];
print "</option>";
print "</select>";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any rows from that query in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 3):

You need the print statements *outside* the loop. You are creating a new menu each time the loop goes around. Try this:

```
print "<select>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
print "<option value=""";
print "disabled="disabled" selected="selected">";
print "Please Select your Undergraduate School";
print "</option>";
print "<option value="1">";
print $row["securityQuestion"];
print "</option>";
print "<option value="2">";
print $row["securityAnswer"];
print "</option>";
}
print "</select>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
echo '<select>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please Select your Undergraduate School</option>';
    echo '<option value="1">'.$row["securityQuestion"].'</option>';
    echo '<option value="2">'.$row["securityAnswer"].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

or

```
print "<select>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print "<option value=""";
    print "disabled="disabled" selected="selected">";
    print "Please Select your Undergraduate School";
    print "</option>";
    print "<option value="1">";
    print $row["securityQuestion"];
    print "</option>";
    print "<option value="2">";
    print $row["securityAnswer"];
    print "</option>";
}
print "</select>";
```

I put the select tags outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your print by using " everywhere, try this

```
print "<option value='1'>".$row['securityQuestion']."</option>";
```

instead of

```
print "<option value="1">$row["securityQuestion"]</option>";
```

Same here, try this

```
print "<option value='' disabled='disabled' selected='selected'> Please Select your Undergraduate School </option>";
```

instead of

```
print "<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected"> Please Select your Undergraduate School </option>";
```

And put your select outside your loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have made some minor mistake

Please try this code..

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die (mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("assignment_3", $conn);

$data = "select securityQuestion, securityAnswer from securityquestiontable";

$result = mysql_query($data, $conn) or die (mysql_error());
print "<select>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

print "<option value=""";
print "disabled="disabled" selected="selected">";
print "Please Select your Undergraduate School";
print "</option>";
print "<option value="1">";
print $row["securityQuestion"];
print "</option>";
print "<option value="2">";
print $row["securityAnswer"];
print "</option>";

}
print "</select>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```